# Maximum number of distinct diagonals generated by permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Given a matrix $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$, let $diag(A)$ be the set of vectors $D \in \{0,1\}^n$ that are the diagonal of one of the $n!$ matrices obtained from $A$ via row permutations.

> What is the maximum size of $|diag(A)|$ over all matrices $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$?

Comment: Is the question for a general upper bound or an upper bound if I know the matrix?

Comment: As in, you can choose any n by n 0-1 matrix you want to maximize this number. 

Answer (score 10):

The answer is $2^n -n$.

Let $I$ be the $n \times n$ identity matrix and let $D$ be a diagonal whose non-zero entries are indexed by $S$.  Further suppose that $D$ does not have exactly one zero entry. Let $\pi$ be a permutation of the rows of $I$ whose fixed points are exactly $S$.  Then the diagonal of $\pi(I)$ is $D$, and there are $2^n-n$ such diagonals.

We finish by showing that $2^n-n$ is the best one can do.

An *$n \times n$ bipartite graph* is a bipartite graph with bipartition $([n]_r, [n]_c)$, where $[n]_r$ and $[n]_c$ are both copies of $[n]$.  Let $G$ be an $n \times n$ bipartite graph.  Define $G'$ to be equivalent to $G$, if $G'$ can be obtained from $G$ by complementing the neighbourhoods of some vertices in $[n_r]$.  Note that the equivalence class of $G$, denoted $[G]$, has size $2^n$.

It is easy to check that the following lemma proves the tightness of the bound.

**Lemma.** For any $n \times n$ bipartite graph $G$, at most $2^n-n$ members of $[G]$ have a perfect matching.

*Proof.* For each $i \in [n]_c$ there is a graph $G^i \in [G]$ such that $i \in [n_c]$ has degree 0 in $G^i$.  Just pick the vertices in $[n]_r$ that are adjacent to $i$ in $G$ and complement their neighbourhoods.  If all $G^i$ are distinct, then the lemma clearly follows.   Otherwise, $G^i=G^j$ for some $i \neq j$.  Thus, both $i$ and $j$ have degree 0 in $G^i$.  But now, the $n$ graphs obtained from $G^i$ by performing a single complementation each do not have a perfect matching.

Comment: This seems to have a slight problem with the case of the configurations with exactly one zero.

Comment: Not with $n=3$ you can't :-)

Comment: I suppose that I cannot generate diagonals that have exactly $n-1$ ones in this way, since if I fix $n-1$ rows, then I automatically fix the last one.  But it seems that I can still get $2^n-n$ diagonals.  

Comment: A clever argument!  One minor comment: I do not think that the current proof of the lemma deals with the case where more than one vertex in [n]_c have exactly the same set of neighbors, but it can be fixed easily.

Comment: Thanks Tsuyoshi!  I edited the proof to handle that case separately.  

Comment: just a minor remark, the same without graphs: 

if two rows (say i-th and j-th) are equal to $r$, then each diagonal has at least two coincidences with $r$ (coincidence means coincidence of one of $n$ coordinate functionals). So, there are at least $n$ forbidden diagonals. If all rows are different, then all their complements are forbidden and we again have $n$ forbidden diagonals.